# Como trazer os valores unicos de uma Array tipo lista conforme a data mais nova Javascript

Tags: javascript, array, lista

Boa tarde

esse script só funciona se o meu Array sempre estiver ordenador da data mais antiga para a mais nova

Como daria

```js
var dados = [
    
        ["09/01/2020","JOAO"],
        ["13/01/2020","PAULO"],
        ["23/01/2020","JOAO"],
        ["01/01/2020","JOAO"],
        ["01/01/2020","PAULO"],
        ["02/01/2020","JOAO"],
        ["02/01/2020","PAULO"],
        ["03/01/2020","JOAO"]
    ]

    var novo_dados = []

    ar = []
    function addArr(el,str){
        if(!el.includes(str)){
            el.push(str)
            return true
        }
    }

    for(i=dados.length-1;i>0;i--){
        nome = dados[i][1]
        if(addArr(ar,nome)){
            novo_dados.push(dados[i])
        }

    }
    console.log(novo_dados)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
  let dados = [
      ["09/01/2020", "JOAO"],
      ["13/01/2020", "PAULO"],
      ["23/01/2020", "JOAO"],
      ["01/01/2020", "JOAO"],
      ["01/01/2020", "PAULO"],
      ["02/01/2020", "JOAO"],
      ["02/01/2020", "PAULO"],
      ["03/01/2020", "JOAO"]
    ];

    const resultado = [];

    dados
      // Primeiro efetua o parse da Data
      .map(a => {
        const ddMMyyyy = a[0].split('/');

        return [
          new Date(ddMMyyyy[2], +ddMMyyyy[1] - 1, ddMMyyyy[0]),
          ...a
        ]
      })
      // Ordena os registros de acordo com o novo campo Date
      .sort((a, b) => {
          if (a[0] < b[0]) {
            return 1;
          } else if (a[0] > b[0]) {
            return -1;
          } else {
            return 0;
          }
      })
      // Os itens agora estão ordenadas, então podemos garantir que a lógica abaixo irá funcionar
      // Para cada item...
      .forEach(item => {
        const nome = item[2];

        // ...verifica se o nome já foi incluido no resultado
        if (!resultado.some(x => x[1] === nome)) {
          resultado.push([item[1], item[2]]);
        }
      });

    console.log(resultado);
```

Comment: O método `sort` espera por um retorno numérico (negativo para menor, igual a 0 para equivalente, positivo para maior). Você está retornando um booleano.

Comment: É verdade @user140828, mas vale lembrar que há uma conversão implícita onde `+true === 1` e `+false === 0` são verdadeiros. Vou efetuar uma alteração para considerar o `-1`

Comment: Não precisa de todos esses `if` e `else`, basta fazer `a[0]` - `b[0]`, pois objetos do tipo `Date` implementam o método `valueOf` para retornar um valor numérico (a quantidade de milissegundos desde a Unix Timestamp).